# How can I make a layout row ignore an empty column?

Tags: html, css, layout, materialize

I'm attempting to build a layout using Materialize CSS framework. I've attached an image of roughly what I'm trying to achieve (Sample A). Unfortunately the second row has a column on the right side that is longer than the other squares. It causes the following row to be pushed lower, leaving a blank area below the left all the columns and throwing off the offset (Sample B). Is there a way I can override that and make it look like Sample A?

I've tried using flexbox, on the second row, but when I do so the sizing of the tiles does not match up with the tiles in the first row, regardless of the "flex grow" I set for each tile.

I've included the code I have so far.

```
<div id="icon-area">
<div class="row">
      <div id="squareicon1" class="square-icon col s4">
        <a href="#"><img class="iconpic" src="res/icons/pic1.jpg"></a>
      </div>
      <div id="squareicon2" class="square-icon col s4">
        <a href="#"><img class="iconpic" src="res/icons/pic2.jpg"></a>
      </div>
      <div id="squareicon3" class="square-icon col s4">
        <a href="#"><img class="iconpic" src="res/pic3.jpg"></a>
      </div>
    </div>


   <div class="row">
      <div id="squareicon1" class="square-icon col s4">
        <a href="#"><img class="iconpic" src="res/icons/pic4.jpg"></a>
      </div>
        <a href="#"><img id="btdimg" src="res/icons/pic5.jpg"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="row" id="fbrow">
      <div id="squareicon1" class="square-icon col s4">
        <a href="#"><img class="iconpic" src="res/icons/pic6.jpg"></a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div id="squareicon1" class="square-icon col s4">
        <a href="#"><img class="iconpic" src="res/icons/pic7.jpg"></a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div id="squareicon1" class="square-icon col s4">
        <a href="#"><img class="iconpic" src="res/icons/pic8.jpg"></a>
      </div>
      <div id="squareicon1" class="square-icon col s8">
        <a href="#"><img class="iconpic" src="res/icons/pic9.jpg"></a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <div id="squareicon1" class="square-icon col s4">
        <a href="#"><img class="iconpic" src="res/icons/pic10.jpg"></a>
      </div>
      <div id="squareicon1" class="square-icon col s4">
        <a href="#"><img class="iconpic" src="res/icons/pic11.jpg"></a>
      </div>
      <div id="squareicon1" class="square-icon col s4">
        <a href="#"><img class="iconpic" src="res/icons/pic12.jpg"></a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As far as the CSS. As follows. Although, I'm relying on Materialize for the column and row spacing.

```
#icon-area{
  padding: 0px !important;
  min-width: 100%;
  margin: 0px !important;
}
.square-icon{
  border-style: outset;
  padding: 0px !important;
}
.iconpic{
  width:100%;
}
div.row{
  margin: 0px !important;
}
```

I feel like the solutions will be something really simple. I just have not been able to think of any elegant solutions; rather, any solution at all.

Comment: Sir, Where is your Sample A And B

Comment: I just realized I forgot to post the image. I'll post it when I get home from work. Thanks for the reminder